# twitter login on phone gap android using cordova

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to login with Twitter on Android using Cordova/PhoneGap. I haved used [this example](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin):

```
TwitterConnect.login(   function(result) {
  console.log('Successful login!');
  console.log(result);
}, function(error) {
  console.log('Error logging in');
  console.log(error);
} );
```

It throws the following error: `uncaught type error: cannot call method 'login' of undefined`.

Comment: did you add the preferences in the config.xml

`<preference name="TwitterConsumerKey" value="<Twitter Consumer Key>" />
<preference name="TwitterConsumerSecret" value="<Twitter Consumer Secret>" />`

if yes then try to remove the platform and re add it

Comment: Yes, I have already added this on config.xml

Comment: @SubirSaha did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that `TwitterConnect` is `undefined`. One of the following reasons could be your case:

1. You did not install the plugin, add the plugin with `cordova plugin add twitter-connect-plugin`
2. You did not test on a real device, since this plugin only has `android` and `ios` support, you can't test in a browser. Run the app on a device with:

   - `cordova run android`
   - `cordova run ios`

Comment: TwitterConnect.login(
      alert("test");
       function(result) {
      console.log('Successful login!');
      console.log(result);
       }, function(error) {
      console.log('Error logging in');
      console.log(error);
       }
     );                           It shows me the alert. so, is there any other calling way for login() of TwiterConnect.js

Comment: If it is now showing your alert() the plugin is defined and all should work. Just handle the things you want in the success callback

Answer (score 0):

you should sure the Fabric API key put it

```
cordova plugin add twitter-connect-plugin --variable FABRIC_KEY=<Fabric API Key>
```